# SQLite SELECT JOIN and VIEWS in C++

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, select

I have a two tables in SQLITE and View where I try to compine these two tables (my idea is to get all the rows from table1 where table1.field1 and table2.field99 have the same value.

```
Tables and View are Table1,Table2 and View1
View code is  "SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON UPPER(Field1) LIKE UPPER(Table2.Field99)"
```

If I run

```
SELECT * FROM View1;
```

or if I run

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON UPPER(Field1) LIKE UPPER(Field99);
```

from sqlite shell it returns the rows just fine.

But if i try to run those SQL statements in C++ with this code:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,SQLStr,-1,&stmt,0)==SQLITE_OK){
   int cols = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);
   printf("Query OK: %s \nColumns: %i\n", SQLStr, cols);
   while(1) {
      status = sqlite3_step(stmt);
      if(status == SQLITE_ROW) {
         printf("This is a row!\n");
      } else if(status == SQLITE_DONE) {
         printf("Rows handled!\n");
         break;
      } else {
         printf("Other status!\n");
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

It just returns:

```
Rows handled: SELECT * FROM View1; 
Columns: 7
Rows handled!
```

But it doesn't return any rows like the shell does. (there should be "This is a row!" printed for every row in query. I tried to add table names to queries but no help. I also tried to run for example SELECT * FROM Table1; and then the C++ returns the rows. Is it so that SQLITE in C++ can't handle JOINS or Views?

Answer (score 1):

if u want to collect the rows then use Sqlite3_exec() API or column API.sqlite3_step() only evaluates the prepared statement it does not fetch the results, for that u have to use different api available or u can use sqlite3_exec which is a wrapper.

check the following link
http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html
http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html

All the best.

Comment: Well I actually tried to use the sqlite3_exec. All goes well if I do SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col1='1'; but if I do SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col2 LIKE 'Text%'; the callback function doesn't get any records. Also if i try to SELECT * FROM View1; It doesn't return any rows. Although it seems the database engine is doing something because the queries seem to take time to run.